# How to download files which are stored in the folder

Tags: files

I need some guidance regarding how to download a file.

Suppose I have a link called "Download." When I click on the particular link a PDF file should be downloaded.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make the link point to the PDF file
2. Make sure that the PDF is public accessible.